# Counting observation week over week as they get updated

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

I built a table frame to count observations week by week and track the change that occur.

This table gives us the weeks of the year and the end date of the periods:

```
Create table MMWR as
SELECT '202140' as MMWR_WEEK,'10/09/2021' as END_DATE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL (SELECT '202141','10/16/2021' FROM DUAL)
UNION ALL (SELECT '202142','10/23/2021' FROM DUAL)
;
```

This adds on the use and demographic elements:

```
Create table MMWR_CATEGORY as (
SELECT 'Product 1' as Prod,'0-50' as AGE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Product 1', '51-100' as AGE FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Product 2', '0-50' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Product 2','51-100' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Product 3', '0-50' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Product 3', '51-100' FROM DUAL
);
```

Below creates out table:

```
CREATE TABLE MMWR_Primary as (select * from MMWR, MMWR_Category);
```

Below is the input table:

```
Current_table:

 SELECT '0001' as Patient_UUID,'08-OCT-2021' as pr_dt_1,'22-OCT-2021' as pr_dt_2,to_date(NULL) as pr_dt_3,'Product1' as pr_1,'Procuct2' as pr_2,to_char(NULL) as pr_3,'0-50' as pr_age_1,'0-50' as pr_age_2,to_char(Null) as pr_age_3 FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL SELECT  '0002', '15-OCT-2021','22-OCT-2021', to_date(NULL),'Product1','Product2',to_char(NULL),  '51-100', '51-100', to_char(Null) FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL SELECT  '0003', '15-OCT-2021','22-OCT-2021', to_date(NULL),'Product2','Product3',to_char(NULL),  '0-51', '51-100', to_char(Null) FROM DUAL
```

Desired result:

```
MMWR Week | End Date | Most Recent Product | Age_Group | Use of Product
202140     10/09/2021   Product 1              0-50          1
202140     10/09/2021   Product 1              51-100        0
202140     10/09/2021   Product 2              0-50          0
202140     10/09/2021   Product 2              51-100        0
202140     10/09/2021   Product 3              0-50          0
202140     10/09/2021   Product 3              51-100        0
202141     10/16/2021   Product 1              0-50          1
202141     10/16/2021   Product 1              51-100        1
202141     10/16/2021   Product 2              0-50          1
202141     10/16/2021   Product 2              51-100        0
202141     10/16/2021   Product 3              0-50          0
202141     10/16/2021   Product 3              51-100        0
202142     10/23/2021   Product 1              0-50          0
202142     10/23/2021   Product 1              51-100        0
202142     10/23/2021   Product 2              0-50          0
202142     10/23/2021   Product 2              51-100        1
202142     10/23/2021   Product 3              0-50          1
202142     10/23/2021   Product 3              51-100        1
```

Current script:

```
Select count(*) 
from Current_table pi 
where (MMWR_Primary.AGE = pi.pr_age_1 and pr_dt_1 <= MMWR_Primary.END_DATE) 
OR (MMWR_Primary.AGE = pi.pr_age_2 and pr_dt_2 <= MMWR_Primary.END_DATE)
OR (MMWR_Primary.AGE = pi.pr_age_3 and pr_dt_3 <= MMWR_Primary.END_DATE) as 'Use of Product'
```

My script returns all the statements, but doesn't update the product and the product age. I'm trying to figure out how to have the product and age updated along with the values in the current_table.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer** (*after update of the question*)
With your tables MMWR and MMWR_CATEGORY you can create either a new cross joined table or a CTE like I did it here (cte is named grid):

```sql
WITH
    grid AS
        (
            Select m.*, c.* 
            From MMWR m 
            CROSS JOIN MMWR_CATEGORY c
            Order By m.MMWR_WEEK, c.PROD
        ),
```

Next is your data with the products used - I will define it as another CTE (named it tbl)....

```sql
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT  '0001' as PATIENT_UUID,To_Date('08-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy') as PR_DT_1, To_Date('22-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy') as PR_DT_2,Null as PR_DT_3,'Product 1' as PR_1,'Product 2' as PR_2, Null as PR_3,'0-50' as PR_AGE_1,'0-50' as PR_AGE_2,Null as PR_AGE_3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
            SELECT  '0002', To_Date('15-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),To_Date('22-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), NULL,'Product 1','Product 2',Null,  '51-100', '51-100', Null FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
            SELECT  '0003', To_Date('15-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'),To_Date('22-OCT-2021', 'dd-MON-yyyy'), NULL,'Product 2','Product 3',Null,  '0-50', '51-100', Null FROM DUAL
        ),
```

You should be sure that your data columns have appropriate types and values. There are some differences in your question regarding this - like 'Product 1' and 'Product1' - they are not the same. Be especially carefull with the columns of type DATE too.
Next thing to do is to prepare the above data for correct future join with your grid (above). One of the ways to do it is in another CTE (prod_use) like this:

```sql
  prod_use AS
        (
            Select PATIENT_UUID "PATIENT_ID", PR_AGE_1 "AGE", PR_1 "PROD", PR_DT_1 "DATE_OF_USE" From tbl Union All
            Select PATIENT_UUID "PATIENT_ID", PR_AGE_2 "AGE", PR_2 "PROD", PR_DT_2 "DATE_OF_USE" From tbl Union All
            Select PATIENT_UUID "PATIENT_ID", PR_AGE_3 "AGE", PR_3 "PROD", PR_DT_3 "DATE_OF_USE" From tbl     
        )
/*  R e s u l t :
PATIENT_ID AGE    PROD      DATE_OF_USE
---------- ------ --------- -----------
0001       0-50   Product 1 08-OCT-21   
0002       51-100 Product 1 15-OCT-21   
0003       0-50   Product 2 15-OCT-21   
0001       0-50   Product 2 22-OCT-21   
0002       51-100 Product 2 22-OCT-21   
0003       51-100 Product 3 22-OCT-21   
0001                                    
0002                                    
0003                               
*/
```

Now this resulting dataset  could be joined to the grid data so we can create the main SQL to get you result that you asked for. The main SQL is here....

```sql
SELECT
    g.*,
    CASE WHEN u.PROD Is Not Null Then 1 ELSE 0 END "USE_OF_PROD"
FROM
    grid g
LEFT JOIN 
    prod_use u ON(u.PROD = g.PROD And u.AGE = g.AGE And u.DATE_OF_USE Between g.END_DATE - 6 And g.END_DATE)
ORDER BY
    g.MMWR_WEEK, g.PROD, g.AGE
```

The result with the data from this updated answer is:

| MMWR_WEEK | END_DATE | PROD | AGE | USE_OF_PROD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 0-50 | 1 |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202140 | 09-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 51-100 | 1 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 0-50 | 1 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202141 | 16-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 1 | 51-100 | 0 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 0-50 | 1 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 2 | 51-100 | 1 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 0-50 | 0 |
| 202142 | 23-OCT-21 | Product 3 | 51-100 | 1 |

Regards...

Comment: I have updated my question to create a dummy table. What I am looking for is for the counts to update in relation to the date of the row. What sequence do I use, I tried OR, to have SQL look at each date after another. Is the issue that I have it wide right now, and I should be iterated long?

Comment: @Boudu - I have just posted the updated answer. Regards...